# Leaking Quriable objects to upper layers

Tags: entity-framework, user-interface, service, repository, data-access-layer

i have an application that is flexible, that the user can:

- 1. filter by any field
- 2. sort by any multiple of fields.
- 3. and because it will run in ASP.Net Site + some Xamarin C# Apps, i will also have paging in it.
- 4. For network performance, it will send projection on the required fields that will be shown.

So if i include in each "Service" method, a parameter "**UQueryConstraints**", that can send filter expression + oderBy expression + page numbers + Projection of the fields, to be used by the Repository, which will apply it to the DBContext, is this is going to be considered a Data leak to the domain services or not?

as seen in this Pic:
       http://1drv.ms/1Ngi3Kn
[image: Layered project]
e.g.:

notice:

- "UQueryConstraints", it will not leak any "IQueryable".
- The "AmbientDbContextLocator", from:

  ```
  <http://mehdi.me/ambient-dbcontext-in-ef6/>
  <https://github.com/mehdime/DbContextScope>
  ```

  public class UIView
  {

  ```
  public static void Display()
  {
      object constraintsB = new UQueryConstraints<Car>().Filter(x => x.carNo <= 6).SortBy(x => x.eName).Page(1, 5);
      //.Projection( field1, field2, field3)
      Debug.WriteLine("---------------test CarModel -------------------");
      CarModel carModel1 = new CarModel();
      carModel1.printCars(constraintsB);

  }
  ```

  }

  public class CarModel
  {

  ```
  private CarService _carService = new CarService();
  void printCars(UQueryConstraints<Car> constraints)
  {
      foreach ( c in _carService.getCarsList("", constraints)) {
          Debug.WriteLine("Reading from converted back: aName =" + c.aName + ", eName = " + c.eName);
      }

  }
  ```

  }

  public class CarService
  {

  ```
  public IList<Car> getCarsList(string Text, UQueryConstraints<Car>    constraints)
  {
      object dbContextScopeFactory = new DbContextScopeFactory();
      object ambientDbContextLocator = new AmbientDbContextLocator();

      using (dbContextScope == dbContextScopeFactory.Create()) {
          //after creating the Scope:
          //1. create the repository
          //2. call repository functions
          object carRep = new CarRepository(ambientDbContextLocator);
          return carRep.getCarsList("", constraints);
      }

  }
  ```

  }

  public class CarRepository : URepositoryFramwork.URepository
  {
      public CarRepository(IAmbientDbContextLocator contextLocator)
      {
          base.New(contextLocator);

  ```
  }

  public IList<Car> getCarsList(string Text, UQueryConstraints<Car> constraints)
  {
      object query = this.DataSet.Where(constraints.FilterExpression);
      //.Select(constraints._projection2)

      IList<Car> items;

      if (constraints == null) {
          items = query.ToList();
      } else {
          items = constraints.ApplyTo(query).ToList();

      }

      return items;
  }
  ```

  }

Regards.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i edited the question to include:
notice:
 * "UQueryConstraints", it will not leak any "IQueryable".
 * The "AmbientDbContextLocator", from:
  http://mehdi.me/ambient-dbcontext-in-ef6/
  https://github.com/mehdime/DbContextScope

Answer (score 0):

Here are few points.

- You don't need `UQueryConstraints` at all and you don't need to do any filtering in the UI at all.
- I'd ague that the model is something that needs to be returned from the service so I wouldn't create `CarModel` in the UI layer and then pushed values to it, it doesn't make sense to me.
- I'd have a method on the service that *request* some data and then returns it in some shape or form to the UI.
- I'd inject the service to `UIView`.
- I don't understand why there's so much *noise* around the context and why do you create it in *getCarsList* it seems like *getCarList* should be a class called *RequestCars* and both the repository and the service should be removed in favor of something like depicted in the [command pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern).

I don't like the whole abstraction here at all, seems like over engineering to me and who says that IQueryable should be abstracted? it's like abstracting language/framework features whereas you should abstract domain features and only **when** necessary.

Abstracting 3rd-party frameworks can be fine to some extent but this isn't one of these cases.

Comment: 1. I need to pass the orderBy and the paging from the UI to the Context, so i don't return all the hundreds of thousands of rows to the UI, especially if its over the internet.
2. The model comes from the MVC pattern.
3. N/A
4. Thinkable but to the Model.
5. Repository is where all "Linq to SQL" is placed, so they will be in one place, Service, Is where the Business logic lies.
6. Leaking IQueryable to upper layers, give the possibility to use "Linq to sql" every where in the layers, plus gives the danger of sql injection hacking.
i appreciate it, it gave time to rethink some things.

Comment: 1. Yes you do need to pass your pagination data to the context, somehow, you're just doing the logic on the wrong layer.
2. Just because your architecture is MVC doesn't mean that you need to create it in the UI layer. patterns != implementation
3. Okay.
4. I don't understand what you mean.
5. I know what is a repository but I don't think you need it in this case, just my opinion.
6. IQueryable is not specific to the data layer! you can avoid abstracting everything and only use a service layer unless you need to centralize logic across services. SQL Injection has nothing to do with anything.

Comment: Thank you for your good time, to look on to my question, and give your very good and interesting discussion, your comment on #6, is another intersting idea to think about it. I am thinking of re-updating my question with a full working solution from the start. Regards, and thax again. :)